# Laravel Unhandled Exception Undefined index: argv on core.php line 218

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I like to think my Google-fu skills are fairly decent, but I cannot find a solution to this particular issue.  I am running laravel on my dev box on my local server.  I am running nginx, PHP Version 5.4.6-1 on a Debian Mint machine.

When I point my browser to my local box, I am getting the following error message:

```
Unhandled Exception

Message:

Undefined index: argv
Location:

/var/www/laravel/laravel/core.php on line 218
```

That particular snippet of code looks as follows:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Set The CLI Options Array
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If the current request is from the Artisan command-line interface, we
| will parse the command line arguments and options and set them the
| array of options in the $_SERVER global array for convenience.
|
*/

if (Request::cli())
{
    $console = CLI\Command::options($_SERVER['argv']);

    list($arguments, $options) = $console;

    $options = array_change_key_case($options, CASE_UPPER);

    $_SERVER['CLI'] = $options;
}
```

Any suggestions out there on how I might go about resolving this particularly annoying issue? Thanks!

Comment: Look for the php.ini setting `register_argc_argv`

Comment: Just a note, keeping this set to `Off` is recommended for performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mario for the heads up, didn't think the problem was a PHP configuration setting, now I know to look into it from a broader perspective.  I found the setting and toggled it over on the php.ini.  I restarted the php service (since it runs separate from nginx, unlike Apache) and it worked like a charm.